# Importing shapefile and geolocation satellite images correctly in SketchUp

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sketchup

I have a shapefile (also other relevant files, shared in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10I-p0Uogk_gmsPueRzuwnYneP36vD9hW?usp=sharing)) which needs to be imported into `SketchUp Pro` (version 23.0.419 64bit).

At first I loaded satellite images from `geolocation` menu as a base map.
To import shapefiles, I installed `spirix_shapefile_importer.rbz` from [this web site](https://sites.google.com/site/spirixcode/code?authuser=0).
CRS of the shapefile is converted into WGS84 (EPSG:4326).
(If I chose `No` in `Geolocate`, imported shp was not found)

[image]

However, location of the imported polygons does not fit to the satellite images.

[image]

This is the correct one shown in QGIS.

[image]

I think it happens due to several reasons:

1. Location of imported satellite image is automatically set at the center of the XYZ axis.
2. Location of shapefile is automatically aligned based on the XYZ axis.
   I checked this behavior by adding some polygons at left-bottom side. If I add some polygons, location of imported polygons were adjusted based on newly added polygons.

I am not sure which caused this issue but it returns polygons with wrong location anyway.
Is anyone who faced the same problem or who solved this issue? I hope if we could use any other plugins which can locate shapefiles in appropriate position.